# Jinja2 templating - extend 2 level

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I have a base.html file that have blovk content and extended by manage.html. and that manage.html has a block sub_manage which is extended by internet_market.html, so visually it looks like:

```
|- base.html (block content)
|--manage.html (extends base.html)
|---sub_manage.html (extends manage.html)
```

when I render_template mange.html everything works fine, but when I try to render_template sub_manage.html the css/javascript does not work. What can I do to overcome this issue?

here is my base.html

```
<head>  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left_sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li class="main"><a href="{{ url_for('cabinet.index', current = 'main') }}"> + Главная</a></li>
            <li class="main"><a href="{{ url_for('cabinet.orders') }}">Заказы</a></li>
            <li class="main"><a href="{{ url_for('cabinet.manage') }}"> - Управление сайтом</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

here is my manage.html file:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% block content %} 
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="dropdown active"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="manage_menu_settings">
        {% include 'admin/manage/site_figuraiton.html' %}
    </div>

    {% block sub_manage%}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

and here is internet_market.html

```
{% extends "admin/manage.html" %}
{% block sub_manage %}  
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane {% if current == 'delivery_settings' %} active{% endif %}" id="delivery_settings">
            Настройки доставки, корзины и оплаты
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane {% if current == 'delivery_type' %} active{% endif %}" id="delivery_type">
            Добавить способы доставки
        </div>
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: Does the space matter between the names and the `%` symbol?

Comment: no it does not metter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.
the problem was that I links that I used for css and js file where relative links, thus when trying to render the 2 level extend it did not find css/js. so it was like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
```

but then I changed these links to dynamic links with url_for and it worked like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for("static", filename = "css/bootstrap.min.css")}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for("static", filename = "js/bootstrap.min.js")}}"></script>
<style type="text/css">
```